# Why does my program not display the output in correct order?

Tags: c++, cin, cout

I want to create a program that asks the user to input values.

The program will ask the user if they want to add more information but when the user wants to add another piece of information the output displays:

First-Question: Answer
Question: Answer
Second-Question:
Question: Answer

[image: Error]

This is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

void IssueBooks() {

    vector<string> bookID;
    vector<string> bookTitle;
    vector<string> bookAuthor;
    vector<string> bookIssuer;

    string ID;
    string  Title, Author, Issuer;
    char question;

    //get bookID
    cout << "Enter book ID: "<<endl;
    getline(cin, ID);
    bookID.push_back(ID);

    //get bookTitle
    cout << "Enter book title: "<<endl;
    getline(cin, Title);
    bookTitle.push_back(Title);

    //get bookAuthor
    cout << "Enter book author: "<<endl;
    getline(cin, Author);
    bookAuthor.push_back(Author);

    //get bookIssuer
    cout << "Enter Issuer Name: "<<endl;
    getline(cin, Issuer);
    bookIssuer.push_back(Issuer);

    ofstream out("IssueRecord.txt");

    for (int j = bookID.size() - 1 ; j >= 0 ; j--) {
        out << bookID[j] << " " << bookTitle[j] << " " << bookAuthor[j] 
<< " " << bookIssuer[j]<<endl;
    }

    cout << "Do you want to add more books? <Y/N>" << endl;
    cin >> question;

    switch(question) {
    case 'Y' :
        IssueBooks();
        break;
    case 'y' :
        IssueBooks();
        break;

    case 'N' :
        break;
    case 'n' :
        break;

    default :
        cout << "Invalid input, try again !" << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    IssueBooks();

   return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to say that an empty string isn't valid input?  Then check it

Comment: not related to the question, but I don't see a good reason to write this recursively rather than adding a loop inside the main function

Comment: no, at the first time it will be 
question:
answer
question:
answer

but at second time if user want to add another information
it will be 
question:
question:

answer

i want the output like the first

Comment: Read the duplicate question. If you're using formatted extraction (which you *are* with you y/n prompt), your input stream continues to harbor the trailing newline you entered upon hitting thumping <enter> on your keyboard following your y/n choice. Consuming the input stream through `'\n'` should handle that, and the duplicate question shows ways to do that.